# I see 'yarn install --network-timeout 1000000000' to increase timeout. Does anyone know how many seconds this is?

Tags: yarnpkg, package-managers

I see 'yarn install --network-timeout 1000000000' to increase the timeout. Does anyone know how many seconds this is?  And, is there someplace where I can see the documentation for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`yarn help` tells us:

```
--network-timeout <milliseconds>    TCP timeout for network requests
```

1,000,000,000 milliseconds is a million seconds, or about 11 days.